# Can I achieve typesafety by Key within a HashMap?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

Following scenario to solve: I need to create a class which will give back or store a List of Fruits, depending on a given id+classtype. So I was questioning myself, which `Collection` to use and If i'll be able to store all fruitlists within the same `Collection` for simplycity. I deceided to give a single `HashMap` a try to store all lists, since the key-value principle sounds familar to my usecase, just that it might need a bit of more complex key, because I need two aspects (in my case the id and the fruits class), to identify the value.

So I created an own key object:

```
class FruitKey
{
  int                     id;
  Class<? extends Fruits> type;

  public FruitKey( int id, Class<? extends Fruits> type )
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
  }

  //equals, hashcode, etc.
}
```

After creating a `Map<FruitKey, List<? extends Fruits>>`, putting works perfecty fine, but of course when I try to get my FruitLists out of the Map, I can't garantee a specific fruit type and have to cast the result:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  Map<FruitKey, List<? extends Fruits>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();

  Apple oneApple = new Apple();
  List<Apple> manyApples = new ArrayList<>();
  manyApples.add( oneApple );

  fruitMap.put( new FruitKey( 1, Apple.class ), manyApples);

  //Any way to avoid typesafty and cast?
  List<Apple> myApples = (List<Apple>) fruitMap.get( new FruitKey( 1, Apple.class ) );
}
```

Since the classtype is already included in the key, I somehow thought I can connect these with the maps value, but unfortunatly I did not succed, without making the map dedicated to a special fruit. Do you see any chances to avoid my typesafty/classcast issues, or can recommend another collectiontype to achive my aim? Of course I could create a Map for each fruit, but since there are a lot of yummi fruits out there, I tried to avoid it, cause I would always have to differ between them.

In short, this is what i want:

```
List<Apple> apples = SomeCollection.get( Key(id, Apple.class) );
```

The reason there is an Id as well is, because there can be several Lists of Apples within the same Map, as well as several Lists of other Fruits.

Comment: I don't think you can but you could provide a generic convenience method that does it `return (T) fruitMap.get(...);`

Comment: You might be interested in the ClassToInstanceMap type in Guava. It has a couple of implementations (see All Known Implementing Classes). http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a heterogenous container. You will still have to cast inside the container, but due to the generic methods and the `final` of the class the cast is safe and you can suppress the warning.

It is safe because the generic `put` ensures that you could never put anything in that would fail the cast.

```
public final class SomeCollection {

     private Map<FruitKey<? extends Fruits>, List<? extends Fruits>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();

     //safe cast
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public <T extends Fruits> List<T> get(FruitKey<T> key)
     {
         return (List<T>) fruitMap.get(key);
     }

     public <T extends Fruits> void put(FruitKey<T> key, List<T> fruits)
     {
         fruitMap.put(key, fruits);
     }
}
```

with a typed `FruitKey`

```
class FruitKey<T extends Fruits>
{
   int                     id;
   Class<T> type;

   public FruitKey( int id, Class<T> type )
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.type = type;
   }     
}
```

### edit

You could also create an inner class `Key<T>` inside `SomeCollection`, which encapsulates a `FruitKey` of the basket and with the appropriate `hashCode` and `equals`.

```
private Map<Key<? extends Fruits>, List<? extends Fruits>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();

//safe cast
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Fruits> List<T> getBasket(T fruit)
{
    Key<T extends Fruit> = new Key<T>(fruit.getBasketId());
    return (List<T>) fruitMap.get(key);
}
//or
//safe cast
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Fruits> List<T> getBasket(Class<T> klass, FruitKey key)
{
    Key<T extends Fruit> = new Key<T>(key);
    return (List<T>) fruitMap.get(key);
}

public <T extends Fruits> void addToBasket(T fruit, List<T> fruits)
{
    Key<T extends Fruit> = new Key<T>(fruit.getBasketId());
    fruitMap.put(key, fruits);
}
```

Comment: This looks promissing. I would prefer making FruitKey a private inner class from SomeCollection, since it is an Implementation Detail. Imagine the API user wants to put an apple in an specific list within that HashMap. SomeCollection offers a method: addToBasket( apple ) without the need to add id and type information. Assumed every Fruit has a basketId, which is the FruitKey id, do you see any chance to generate the key from an Apple instance?

Comment: Yeah I think that should be possible. I edited my post to make it fit what I think you described. Obviously, with the get method you either need a fruit or the class of the fruit to fetch a basket.